# Can Paillier Homomorphic Encryption handle more than one binary plaintext?

Tags: number-theory, cryptography, group-homomorphism

I am reading about Paillier Homomorphic Encryption, given here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paillier_cryptosystem

I have two questions:

1) Is this restricted to only two plaintexts? Can I extend the homomorphic properties to more than two plaintexts?

2) Refer to:

$D(E(m_1, r_1)E(m_2, r_2) \mod n^2) = m_1 + m_2 \mod n$

what would happen if $(m_1 + m_2) > n$? Wouldn't that lose data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This will work with any number of plaintexts, $m=\left[m_1,\cdots ,m_k\right]$:
   $$
   \begin{align}
   D\left(E\left(m_1,r_1\right)\cdots E\left(m_k,r_k\right)\right)
   & = D\left(g^{m_1}r_1^N\cdots g^{m_k}r_k^N\right)\\
   &=D\left(\left(g^{m_1} \cdots g^{m_k}\right)\left(r_1^N\cdots r_k^N\right)\right) \\
   &=D\left(\left(g^{m_1 +\cdots + m_k}\right)\left(r_1 \cdots r_k\right)^N\right)\\
   &=D\left(E\left(m_1+\cdots +m_k,r_1 \cdots r_k\right)\right)\\
   &=m_1 +\cdots + m_k
   \end{align}
   $$

We can see this last step is valid, as $\gcd(a,N)=1$ and $\gcd(b,N)=1\implies \gcd(ab,N)=1$ which we can extend infinitely.

2. That is correct, if $m_1 + m_2 > N$ then there will be a loss of information. This is stated in the original equation. To add together larger numbers, we must choose a larger $N$